# Windows Forms Designer Float overflow

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, floating-point, overflow, designer

I'm not sure what's changed, but for some reason I'm getting a problem with Visual Studio 2008 Windows Forms Designer:

> C++ CodeDOM parser error: Line: 1978, Column: 80 --- Float overflow

The call stack doesn't seem to point to any of my code either:

```
 at Microsoft.VisualC.CppCodeParser.OnMethodPopulateStatements(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 at System.CodeDom.CodeMemberMethod.get_Statements()
 at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
 at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)
```

If I compile and run the code it works fine. Does anyone have any idea why I might be seeing this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I'd replaced the following:

```
this->m_cmbStepSelect->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(5) {L"String1", L"String2", L"String3", L"String4", L"String5"});
```

With:

```
#define NUM_OF_STRINGS (5)
this->m_cmbStepSelect->Items->AddRange(gcnew cli::array< System::Object^  >(NUM_OF_STRINGS) {L"String1", L"String2", L"String3", L"String4", L"String5"});
```

...which threw the designer.